# How can I dynamically display Total number of items from the Database in a blade view in Laravel 7

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm quite new to Laravel, In my Dashboard I would like to display Total number of projects coming from MySQL database table, called "projects" into a Bootstrap card (See the Screenshot) I have some code in my Controller that gets Total number of Projects from the Database but I'm getting "Undefined variable" error. I know my mistake is in my blade view. For now I'm just displaying static data in Bootstrap card. Please Help.

In my HomeController:

```
public function showTotals()
    {
        $allProjects = Project::count();

        return view('dashboard.index', compact('allProjects'));
    }
```

In my View:

```
<div class="col-md-3"
<div class="card-counter primary">
<i class="fa fa-id-card"></i>
<span class="count-numbers">{{ $allProjects }}</span>
<span class="count-name">Projects</span>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your function `showTotals()` is not the one called in your route.

I suppose the route is calling in `public function index()`, where you actually should pass the `$allProjects` variable.

Either you call this in your index function or you change the `routes/web.php` to call `HomeController@showTotals()`. I suggest you should use the first one..

Please post your `routes/web.php`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. My mistake was that I put my code inside `showTotals()` function instead of `index()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Change to array in return view.Since count return number not an array

```
  return view('dashboard.index', ['allProjects'=>$allProjects]);
```

Since view expects second parameter to be an array

```
 view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
```

Comment: I have tried that but I'm getting the same error, is there anything I need to change in my blade view?

Comment: you can whether value set or not {{ $allProjects??null }}

Comment: first dd( $allProjects); what you get

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was putting my code in `showTotals()` function instead of `index()` function as mentioned by @Alpy

Comment: okay.glad that you have solved your issue